# Fiddler/Firebug for Adobe AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, air, fiddler

How does one inspect the HTTP traffic in Adobe Air?  Obviously because it's running outside of a browser you can't use firebug ...

I've tried this: [ServiceCapture](http://www.kevinlangdon.com/serviceCapture/)

but it doesn't work either... (nothing shows up in the log). I also don't really want to pay for a program.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will do that - it works at the network level, so it will work with any web technology.

The most important thing to know about is the right-click "Follow TCP/IP stream" command, which will show you your app's HTTP conversation.

Comment: thanks..installed on win7, looks like this is what I need. Where is this 'follow tcp/ip stream' option though?

Comment: @dmose: It's on the right-click menu when you right-click on a sequence of captured network packets.

Answer (score 8):

Try Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: I have fiddler but it only captures browser traffic..Adobe Air runs outside of the browser..

Comment: Nope... From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250446(VS.85).aspx, " Fiddler is an HTTP debugging proxy that logs **all HTTP traffic** between your computer and the Internet". Then later it states "Microsoft Windows Internet Services (WinInet), the HTTP layer used by Internet Explorer". I've successfully used it with a lot of applications bisides the browser. Maybe Adobe AIR does not go through WinInet.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My problem was I was testing on an asp.net development server on port 59003 ... when i made a standard request to :80 it worked! thnks.

Comment: Fiddler can capture traffic to any port. When debugging traffic bound for Localhost, you need to do some tricks though: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic

Answer (score 6):

Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) works very well with AIR and has built-in AMF decoding, allowing the inspection of AMF requests/responses.

Comment: I use this all the time, well worth the license cost.

Answer (score 2):

I believe both [HTTPScoop](http://tuffcode.com/) (for mac) and [HTTP Analyzer](http://ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/) (Windows) will let you watch HTTP traffic from non-browser programs (I can see requests made by the Google Notifier, for example).